# JSON data not creating from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to convert NSDictionary to JSON object to send it over network. But I am getting an error in converting dictionarty to NSData.
Here is my code:

```
NSError *error=nil;
        NSDictionary *loginfbDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

        NSData *d=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:loginfbDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
        NSLog(@"error===>%@",error);
 BOOL f=[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:d];
```

When I log my dictionary befor converting it into NSData I got it printed. But When I  wrote that code after converting dictionary into data I got nothing. I put Debug point after NSData *d... But my code is not executing after that line. I am writing this code in appdelegate file.

Object Contain:

```
  NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         @"loginVia",
                         @"userName",
//                             @"password",
                         @"firstName",
                         @"lastName",
                         @"gender",
                         @"dob",
                         @"email",
                         @"fb_url",
                         nil];

        NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"facebook",
                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"],
 //                                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"password"],
                            [FBUserProfileData objectForKey:@"first_name"],
                            [FBUserProfileData objectForKey:@"last_name"],
                            [FBUserProfileData objectForKey:@"gender"],
                            ds,
                            [FBUserProfileData objectForKey:@"email"],
                            fb_url,
                            nil];
```

Comment: What is in `objects`?

Comment: there is values in objects according keys

Comment: I guessed that. What are the objects? Presumably something that can't be converted into JSON...

Comment: when I print loginfbDictionary before NSDATA *d got all values but when I print it after that line I didnt get anything and also in error I not gettign anything

Comment: wait I upadte my question with object

Comment: put some more code, show what are the objects and keys...

Comment: `BOOL f=[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:d];` should be `BOOL f=[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:loginfbDictionary];` and run before you try to convert to JSON.

Comment: `ds` is an `NSDate` ?

Comment: post your json output format

Comment: are you sure none of the object values is passed as nil. If the dict key value pair is not matched then it might throw error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're adding an `NSDate` or an `NSURL` object into your dictionary to be converted to JSON. The problem is that JSON doesn't have a "Date" or a "URL" data type. So you need to convert the date / URL into a string (`NSString`) and add that instead.

Comment: NSString *ds=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[f2 stringFromDate:sendDate]];
            NSLog(@"date srinf %@",ds);

Comment: `fb_url` then, `NSString` or `NSURL`?

Comment: NSString *s=[nsstring stringwithcontentofurl:URl encoding:NSEncodingLosyy error:&error];
This is write method to convert url to string?

Comment: That downloads the content from the URL. You might want to look at using `absoluteString`.